# Reverse substring matching on an array of objects in jq

Tags: arrays, json, regex, string, jq

Let's say I have an array like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "path": "/home/user"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "path": "/user"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "path": "/var"
  }
]
```

And I want the id of the object whose path is a substring of a given pattern, so if I provide `/home/user/data` I want to get 1.

I know I can check whether the given pattern is a substring of the path using for example `map(.path | test("/home.*"))`, but how can I do it the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flip input and argument, you can store one into a variable, and reset the context as you see fit. For instance, using `startswith`:

```bash
.[] as {$id, $path} | $id | select("/home/user/data" | startswith($path))
```

```
1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c3P6XSLPqEP)

---

The pattern is best provided using the `--arg` option, which also makes it a variable:

```bash
jq --arg pattern '/home/user/data' '
  .[] as {$id, $path} | $id | select($pattern | startswith($path))
'
```

---

Note: I used `startswith` because you just wanted `1` to be returned. The real substring checker `contains` already has a flipped version built in, called `inside`. With this, you don't need the variables for flipping, but it also returns `1` and `2` as both are actually contained within the given pattern:

```bash
.[] | select(.path | inside("/home/user/data")).id
```

```
1
2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CRY3ew7v2--)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the insights!
Now, alongside the id I would like to output the remaining part of the string, i.e. the part outside the matched pattern, could you add that as well? :)

Comment: @xeruf Do you mean something like [this](https://jqplay.org/s/acfsqa-1PZa)? It outputs `1` and `"/data"`. Add the `-r` option to decode JSON.

Comment: Ah, I love command-line wizardry, thank you so much :)